# R Shiny: Update a Dataframe after a user's change of input

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am trying for way too long now to change an existing dataframe having the structure :

```
A<-c(1,NA)
B<-c(2,NA)

df<-data.frame(A,B)

>df
          A     B
1         1     2 
2         NA    NA
```

I would like to display the dataframe in the UI, and alter a csv-file overwriting it with the data of the dataframe.

**Path I would like to achieve:**

- The dataframe is initially loaded into R.
- The user chooses a value at a slider in the app. Then this value should be written into A2 to overwrite the NA. Afterwards the whole thing should be written into a CSV-File.

The isolated part for the problem so far:

```
library("shiny")
x<- .. #(csvupload)

ui <- fluidPage(

#Copy of x
xchange<-x 

#The slider where the user chooses a value
sliderInput("slider", label = "Slider", min = 0, 
           max = 3,step=0.001, value =1),            

#Print of the changed database
textOutput("xchange"))    


server<-function(input,output,session){

observeEvent(input$Slider,{
    x$A[x$Szenarios=="2"]<-input$slider
 }) 

output$xchange<-renderValues({
    input$x})
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error code:argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
Warning: Error in reactiveValues: All arguments passed to reactiveValues() must be named.
```

I guess I use observeEvent,renderValues or both wrong or textOutput is simply a bad idea to use here. But..I do not know...

I do not really need it to be printed but I thought it might be the best way to control if what I do is correct or not.

Comment: Your data frame should be in a reactive call so that it can be updated continually when a user clicks on the observe event button - also please provide a reprex example so we can see what data you have, then we can make a ui and server shiny app example for yoou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you. It gets a bit wonky with all the different versions of the data being uploaded and written to.

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(

#The slider where the user chooses a value
sliderInput("slider", label = "Slider", min = 0, 
           max = 3,step=0.001, value =1),            

#Print of the changed database
textOutput("xchange")

)    


server<-function(input,output,session){

#Read data into server not ui
data<-read.csv("x")

#Re-read data for any changes, write to csv new changes, ignore startup
observeEvent(input$slider,{
data<-read.csv("x")
data$A[2]<-input$slider
write.csv(data,"data.csv")
ignoreInit=T
})

#Reactive variable xchange that updates the values of data
xchange<-reactive({
data<-read.csv("x")
data$A[2]<-input$slider
data
})

#Display the most recent file, with the most recent changes
output$xchange<-renderTable({
xchange()
})


}
```

Comment: I used tableOutput instead of textOutput (I could have guessed in advance that a table might be a good idea for a dataframe) and then your code seems to work perfectly. However I still have a question.In the definition of the reative function of xchange you read the data and load it to data and change the value of the dataframe again. Can you not just change it in the ObserveEvent above to "x" and just read it in xchange? Is it to preserve the original data?Now you load the new value to a new csv instead but you do not use it later in xchange. Is there a reason?

Comment: @Michelle I agree this is somewhat of a strange way to go about it now that I am looking back. The main reason this was done is because `observeEvent` cannot return any variables, so to output the data to the ui we would need to use a `render` function inside the `observeEvent` (which I try to avoid), or return data to the main environment to be output. As far as loading in the data, that is the weird bit as we are constantly overwriting and reading the data so I put the extra read function in to ensure it was the proper version being read in. Although, this could be made more efficient.

Comment: I see. I actually have a simular problem where I want to source an R-code in the observeEvent every time the slider-input changes and load the output into a table. The problem is that I can not do it exactly this way now (which I hoped^^') because I am loading a different data now (the output of the Sourcecode). Before I could just activate the reative-function through the change of the input$slider. Now the input$slider causes the Sourcecode to run but it is not part of the output anymore so I do not know how to create a reactive function for my rendertable. I tried combining ObserveEvent

Comment: and readtive, however it did not work...Do you maybe have a suggestion?

Comment: @Michelle You can use an `observeEvent` to monitor the changes to the slider, when it is triggered you can source and use your function, and then nest a `renderTable` function inside the `observeEvent` that outputs your results from the sourced function. Since the only time the data will change is related to the slider this should be okay.

Comment: `observeEvent(input$slider,{  
    source("file.R",local=TRUE)
    ignoreInit=T
    xoutput<- readRDS("outputfile.R")
    output$tablex<-renderTable({
      input$xoutput()})
  }) `             produces an error saying attempt to apply non-function...

Comment: @Michelle I would recommend opening a new question. You cannot use `readRDS()` to read a non-RDS file. Also you are treating `xoutput` as a reactive object by using `()` in the call, it is not reactive,`renderTable({ xoutput})` will work.

Comment: Ok thanks I will open a new question. The .R was a typo and xoutput does not work cause it does not update the table. So I guess I am still far away from my answer and I should open a new question.